# Programming logic for income tax calculation

Tags: php, mysql, logic

Is any one who can help me to create PHP or mysql Code for our Office employee salary tax table.
Here is the base for our tax regulation.

```
 If salary is >= 0 and <= 150 it will be 0% (Nill),
 If salary is >= 151 and <= 650 it will be 10% - 15.00,
 If salary is >= 651 and <= 1400 it will be 15% - 47.50,
 If salary is >= 1401 and <= 2350 it will be 20% -117.50,
 If salary is >= 2351 and <= 3550 it will be 25% - 235.00,
 If salary is >= 3551 and <= 5000 it will be 30% - 412.5,
 If salary is >= 5001 it will be 35% - 662.50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_taxed_salary($salary){
  if ($salary <= 150 ){
    return $salary;
  };
  if ($salary <= 650){
    return ( 0.9 * $salary - 15.0 );
  };

 ...
}
```

later in your code you use that function like:

```
$taxed_salary = get_taxed_salary($salary);
```

Comment: "elseif's" might be more appropriate. He also needs a specific output.

Comment: why do you think it would be more appropriate with `elseif`s? - in my opinion that would only make the program flow harder to follow since you'de have one big `if/elseif/else` structure, whereas in my approach every single condition is isolated. What do you mean by needing a specific output?

Comment: The returned taxed salary is unique for each input, meaning `elseif`s are perfectly fine. They also make the function much more flexible. Consider a situation where you need to perform additional calculations in the same function after the taxed salary is calculated. You won't be able to apply conditional factoring to your `if-statements` if each `if-statement` contains a return statement.

Comment: In that case I would wrap the get_taxed_salary into another function and then apply extra calculation there.

Comment: There would be no reason to if you have a perfectly fine function to use. Defining a new function would be less efficient and cause more code clutter. Are you really that uncomfortable with factoring out your return statements? This is basic programming.

Comment: as far as i know, basic programming means keeping one function responsible for one thing only - otherwise you would put all the application in one function, wait, then you wouldn't need functions at all :)

Comment: You don't understand what I'm trying to say here. All of his conditions are *mutually exclusive*. Regardless of whether his post-calculations should be abstracted out of the function or not, returning in each conditional without an important reason to is ridiculous. I know what you're trying to accomplish with your function design, but it's just not appropriately flexible. Let's keep things simple, people.

Comment: I understand perfectly what you mean - is just that we have different definitions for *simplicity* and *code clutterness*. Let's say that another developer has to maintain my code - it sees the call to `get_taxed_salary` with a value of 175 for example - he/she goes to that functions, reads the first 5 lines of code from it and knows instantly what that function does. Whereas if it returned the value at the end of it, the developer had to follow along all the 29384723 lines of code in it (ie: spending time going over 29384718 lines of code) - tell me which of those is the simplest approach?

Comment: I was simply trying to make a point about conventional function design. Your proposal is an uncommon one, which is why I question its utility. Let's agree to disagree. This is not an appropriate place for this argument. Regards, -Collin

Comment: the idea of exiting a code block as fast as possible is not unconventional, exotic or unseen at all ( i mean for any just a little more than entry level developers) every time you have a final value for a piece of business logic, you return it - another case of early return is with parameter validation - if one fails, raise an error and exit

Answer (score 2):

In most countries, that is not how tax works - you don't pay tax at a certain percent based on how much you earn. If that was the case then people who's wages were just above a tax bracket would have a net income after tax lower than someone who earnt just under a tax bracket.

How it really works: you pay tax at different percentages, for each part of your income that falls within each tax bracket. So if you earn $11,000 and there is a tax bracket from 0 to 10,000 and another from 10,000 up to 20,000 then the first 10k earned will be taxed at the first bracket's rate and the remaining 1k will be taxed at the higher rate of the second tax bracket.

Code to calculate tax in this manner:

```
//the tops of each tax band
$band1_top = 14000;
$band2_top = 48000;
$band3_top = 70000;
//no top of band 4

//the tax rates of each band
$band1_rate = 0.105;
$band2_rate = 0.175;
$band3_rate = 0.30;
$band4_rate = 0.33;

$starting_income = $income = 71000; //set this to your income

$band1 = $band2 = $band3 = $band4 = 0;

if($income > $band3_top) {
    $band4 = ($income - $band3_top) * $band4_rate;
    $income = $band3_top;
}

if($income > $band2_top) {
    $band3 = ($income - $band2_top) * $band3_rate;
    $income = $band2_top;
}

if($income > $band1_top) {
    $band2 = ($income - $band1_top) * $band2_rate;
    $income = $band1_top;
}

$band1 = $income * $band1_rate;

$total_tax_paid = $band1 + $band2 + $band3 + $band4;

echo "Tax paid on $starting_income is $total_tax_paid";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly what I needed to calculate income tax in Australia.  (Just had to add one extra tax bracket)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn basic PHP. The solution is trivial.

```
function getTax($salary) {
    $percent = 0;
    $subt = 0;

    if ($salary >= 0 && $salary <= 150) {
        $percent = 10;
        $subt = 15;
    } elseif ($salary >= 151 && $salary <= 650) {
        ...
    } ...

    // do calculations here, ex:
    $final = $salary * $percent / 100 - $subt;
    return $final;
}
```

Edit: Thank you Constantin for the function reminder

Answer (score -1):

Check this, logic in PHP & Perl.

```
function calc_tax($salary) {
    $params = array(array(5001,662.50), array(3551,412.5), array(2351,235.00), array(1401,117.50), array(651,47.50), array(151,15.00), array(0,0));

    foreach ($params as $p) {
        if($salary >= $p[0]) {
            return $p[1];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

foreach (array(100,150,3500,8900) as $sal) {
    echo $sal."==".calc_tax($sal)."\n";
}
```

Perl:

```
sub calc_tax {
    my $sal = shift;
    my @params = ( [ 5001, 662.50 ], [ 3551, 412.5 ], [ 2351, 235.00 ], [ 1401, 117.50 ], [ 651, 47.50 ], [ 151, 15.00 ], [ 0, 0 ] );

    foreach $p (@params) {
        if ( $sal >= $p->[0] ) {
            return $p->[1];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

foreach my $sal (qw[160 3200 8900]) {
    print $sal,"==",calc_tax($sal),"\n";
}
```

Comment: it wasn't me that downvoted you - but your code is not taking in considerations the variable amount of taxes that has to be paid (ie: the percentages) - if you modify it and make it work, I'll upvote your answer because of Perl and the new approach - although it's pretty hard to follow