# PHP Calculate pricing by quantity range price

Tags: php

I have a situation where i need to calculate product price based on the quantity range, here my price range logic

I have a different price classes

From 50 - 200 it's $1/50
From 250 - 500 it's $0.75/50
From 550 - 1000 it's $0.5/50

So if someone orders 1,000
the first 200 would be calculated at $1/50 ($4)
Then from 250 - 500 it would be $0.75/50 so ($4.5)
Then from 550 - 1000 it would be $0.5/50 so ($5)
Total: 4 + 4.5 + 5 = $13.5

In PHP admin i enter the classes in below format in a textarea (this format can be changed whatever is easier)
200|1
500|0.75
1000|0.5

How do i calculate the price based on this price class?

Comment: Not exactly the same but similar logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951553/programming-logic-for-income-tax-calculation/23862932

Answer (score 0):

First of all your ranges are off, they are all missing 50 pieces

> The first 200 pieces would be calculated at `1  / 50`
>   Then from 250 to 500 pieces, it would be `.75 / 50`

---

So breaking it down if you sold 1000 pieces:

- The first 0 - 250 pieces will be sold at `1 / 50`

  - `(250 - 0) * 0.02 = 5`
  - `1000 - (250 - 0) = 750`
  - Remaining amount to sell is 750 pieces
- The next 250 - 550 pieces will be sold at `.75 / 50`

  - `(550 - 250) * 0.015 = 4.5`
  - `750 - (550 - 250) = 450`
  - Remaining amount to sell is 450 pieces
- The next 550 to ??? pieces will be sold at `.5 / 50`

  - `450 * 0.01 = 4.5`
  - Remaining pieces is 0

Bringing the total to: `5 + 4.5 + 4.5 = 14`

---

```
function getPrice($amount) {
    $prices = [
        250     => 1.00 / 50,
        550     => 0.75 / 50,
        1000    => 0.50 / 50,
    ];
    ksort($prices);


    $total = 0.0;
    $lowerbound = 0;
    foreach($prices as $bound => $price) {
        if ($amount < $bound) return $total + ($amount * $price);
        $total += ($bound - $lowerbound) * $price;
        $amount -= ($bound - $lowerbound);
        $lowerbound = $bound;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Alternatively you can calculate the same price by starting with the upperbound

```
function getReversedPrice($amount) {
    $prices = [
        0   => 1.00 / 50,
        250 => 0.75 / 50,
        550 => 0.50 / 50,
    ];
    krsort($prices);

    $total = 0.00;
    foreach($prices as $bound => $price) {
        if ($amount < $bound) continue;
        $total += ($amount - $bound) * $price;
        $amount -= ($amount - $bound);
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add condition that if number is between 50-200 then calculate 1$ for example if number is greater than 200 then calculate 2$ and so on